# My Minecraft Java crashes every time I open it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft Java edition and it was fine, but today when I started it up it got just to the end of the loading screen and stopped. It then crashed, and gave me the message `Open jdk Platform Binary not responding`. How do I fix this?

Comment: How much of RAM does your system have OP?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea how Minecraft works, but I believe your Java runtime may start with low RAM allocation.

Java defines specific parameters to handle the minimum and maximum memory you can allocate. As per [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM160), you can see how Xms and Xmx can be configured.

I suggest you try to increase Xmx value to something bigger than 1Gb.